# Get Tuple of all adjacent elements in List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find all consecutive elements which satisfy the condition `a < X <= b`, and then store them in pairs `(a,b)`.

So far, this finds all `b`:

```
Tuple<Vector2, Vector2> getPointsWithinInterval(double X)
{
    var points = List<Vector2> {...};

    var list_of_b = Points.Skip(1).Where((p, i) =>
        points[i].X < X  &&  X <= p.X                // condition
    );
}
```

**EDIT:** Based off @MattBurland's suggestion, I came up with the somewhat inelegant solution

```
var ranges = Points
    .Skip(1)
    .Where((p, i) =>
        Points[i].X < X && X <= p.X)
    .Select((p, i) => new Tuple<Vector2, Vector2>(Points[i - 1], Points[i]));
```

---

Example:

```
X = 2

(1, 0)
(3, 0)
(1, 0)
(5, 0)
(6, 0)
```

Returns:

```
(1, 0) , (3, 0)
(1, 0) , (5, 0)
```

Comment: What would your key be?  Couldn't multiple `Vector2`s fulfill the "a" condition?

Comment: I agree with Dan this doesn't seem like what you want is really a dictionary.  Maybe a `List<Tuple<Vector2, Vector2>>`?

Comment: @DanField I added an example which hopefully clarifies matters

Comment: Your sample output wouldn't work as a dictionary, but could work as a list of Tuples or some other data structure.

Comment: Ah, yes, I suppose `List<Tuple>` might be better then

Comment: *unfortunately doesn't work because i does not correspond to the index of points*, You could use the `Select` over load that includes the index and select the data and the index together. Then when you do `ToDictionary`, you'd have the index available.

Comment: I don’t understand your input. Can you show *in C# code* how you would call your function with what input?

Comment: You could easily do this with plain `for` iteration, why bother with LINQ?

Comment: See my edit, if your intention is to have the indexes match up with the original List, then you need to select the index before you do any other transformations (including the `Skip`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is solution for abstract points.
It can be extended for Vector2.

```
var pairs = points
    .Take(points.Count - 1)
    .Zip(points.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
    .Where(pair => pair.Item1.X < x && x <= pair.Item2.X)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, would something like this work:

```
var pairs = list_of_b.Select((pair,idx) => 
    new Tuple<Vector2,Vector2>(points[idx-1], points[idx]);
```

**Edit**, actually, because of the `Where` (and the `Skip` actually) that might filter out some items, the indexes in your `Select` would be incorrect. You need to select those indexes from the start. Something like:

```
var ranges = Points
    .Select((p,i) => new { p, i })   // now i will always match the indexes in Points
    .Skip(1)
    .Where(p =>
        Points[p.i].X < X && X <= p.p.X)
    .Select((p) => new Tuple<Vector2, Vector2>(Points[p.i - 1], Points[p.i]));
```

But this does feel awfully inelegant.

Comment: I think so, but it seems like an odd way of doing things

Comment: If you use the static method `Tuple.Create<,>(,)`, the type parameters can be omitted (will be inferred).